# session variable not carrying over

Tags: php, session

I am starting the session in dbconnect.php .The session variable is carrying over to home.php on  my localhost but when i am hosting it on a webserver the session variable is not carrying over.

checklogin.php

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
$username = $_POST['username'] ;   
$_SESSION['user'] = $username ; 
// other code 
?>
```

home.php

```
<?php 
session_start();  
$user = $_SESSION['user'] ;  
echo $user;
// other code 
?>
```

Comment: it could possibly be an issue in the php.ini configuration file I would compare the values from your localhost to the values on your webhost server.

Comment: Have you looked at the error logs ?

Comment: i will check the error log just now just wanted to confirm there is nothing wrong in my code??